# Adding new features to the output of Flatten() layer in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, keras-layer

I am doing image classification. Firstly I am feeding my images to my CNN model in Keras.

I want to add new features at the output of Flatten layer in keras and then feed it to the dense layer(s). How do I write a code for it?

Basically I am using Convolution for images and then at the end I want to add other features like Age Sex etc.

```
max_pool_final = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_final)
flat = Flatten()(max_pool_final)
dense = Dense(128)(flat)
```

Before feeding flat as an input to the dense layer, I want to add a few features to flat. How do I do this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to use the Concatenate layer to append those features to the flattened vector with a new Input layer:

```
otherInp = Input(shape = (n_features, ))
concatenatedFeatures = Concatenate(axis = 1)([flat, otherInp])
dense = Dense(128)(concatenatedFeatures)
```

Comment: My  additional features have a shape of 18324 x 4. But the output coming from my flat layer has dimensions (None,512). This is throwing me an error saying dimensions except concatenation axis must match exactly. So how do I do this

Comment: @NikhilMishra Then you should concatenate around axis 1, I will update my answer.

Comment: But how do I feed my features to other input. WIll doing model.fit([X_train,agp],y) be enough? How will Keras know it, just by the input shapes?

Comment: @NikhilMishra You pass them to model.fit, like model.fit([images, features], Y, ...) Your model now has effectively two inputs. Make sure to update your Model definition to reflect both inputs as well.

Comment: How does Keras distinguish between images and features? Just by the input shape? Or do we need to specify something else in our model?

Comment: Its the order of the inputs, you should read the introduction to the Functional API: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/ Specially the part about Multi-input and multi-output models.