# Concatenating layers in Keras (None,512) and (18577,4)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

How do I concatenate 2 layers in keras, when one of layers has its dimensions (None,512) and the other has dimensions (18577,4). I tried using Concatenate

```
concat_layer = Concatenate()([z1,agp]
```

But this throw me an error telling:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 512), (18577, 4)]
```

The model looks something like this:

```
a1= (Convolution2D(32, filter_dim, activation='linear', 
                    padding='same',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg)))(input_img) 
b1 = (BatchNormalization())(a1)
c1 = (PReLU())(b1)
d1 = (Convolution2D(32, filter_dim, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg)))(c1)
e1 = (BatchNormalization())(d1)
f1 = (PReLU())(e1)
g1 = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))(f1)
h1 = (Dropout(0.2))(g1)

i1= (Convolution2D(64, filter_dim, activation='linear', padding='same',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg)))(h1)
j1 = (BatchNormalization())(i1)
k1 = (PReLU())(j1)
l1 = (Convolution2D(64, filter_dim, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg)))(k1)
m1 = (BatchNormalization())(k1)
n1 = (PReLU())(m1)
o1 = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))(n1)
p1 = (Dropout(0.2))(o1)

q1= (Convolution2D(128, filter_dim, activation='linear', padding='same',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg)))(p1)
r1=q1
s1 = (BatchNormalization())(r1)
t1 = (PReLU())(s1)
u1 = (Convolution2D(128, filter_dim, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg)))(t1)
v1 = (BatchNormalization())(u1)
w1 = (PReLU())(v1)
x1 = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))(w1)
y1 = (Dropout(0.2))(x1)



z1 = (Flatten())(y1)
agp=tf.convert_to_tensor(agp,np.float32)
z1 = Concatenate(axis=1)([z1,agp])

a2 = (Dense(128, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg)))(z1)
b2 = (BatchNormalization())(a2)
c2 = (PReLU())(b2)
d2 = (Dropout(0.2))(c2)

e2 = (Dense(32, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg)))(d2)
f2 = (BatchNormalization())(e2)
g2 = (PReLU())(f2)
h2 = (Dropout(0.3))(g2)
```

My input image has dimensions (32,32,3). I want to concatenate z1(None,512) with  agp (18577,4)

Comment: What do you want to get as a result?

Comment: I want to combine 512 and 4 features together to make it 516. So that I have something like (None,516) or (18577,516) which I can pass on to the next layer

Comment: Please include the code for your model, its a bit hard to see where the problem is.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I added my model

Comment: What's agp and why does it look like you are not giving it with an Input layer?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro agp represents 3 other features of the data apart from image. Here it stands for age gender and position of image. So it has 4 columns and no. of rows equal to training examples(18577). I want to integrate it to my Dense layer, after training my images using Convolution. So that I can use both Images and Other features for classification

Comment: That's not what I asked, I mean why are you converting it to a tensor, it should come from an Input layer. This is what I mentioned in the answer to your other question, you are simply not giving the data in the right way.

Comment: I converted it because the output of Flatten() layer was also a tensor. So Concatenate()  would join 2 tensors. Is this not the proper way of doing it? How do I do it in code?

Comment: I already answered how to do it properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473957/adding-new-features-to-the-output-of-flatten-layer-in-keras/48474401 You *have* to use two Input layers, one for the image and another for the extra features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def create_model(nb_classes, input_shape):
    """Create a NN model."""
    # from keras.layers import Dropout
    from keras.layers import Activation, Input
    from keras.layers import Dense, Concatenate
    from keras.models import Model

    input_ = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = input_

    # Branch in two directions - this can be more
    # complex, of course
    x1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
    x2 = Dense(4, activation='relu')(x)

    # And this is how you use concatenation
    x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x1, x2])

    # And then finish it
    x = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=x)
    return model


model = create_model(10, (512, ))
print(model.summary())
```

gives

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 512)           0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           262656      input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 4)             2052        input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)      (None, 516)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                   dense_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            5170        concatenate_1[0][0]              
====================================================================================================
Total params: 269,878
Trainable params: 269,878
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```